# web scarping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I solve the below error? Selenium was installed successfully.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver")
```

```
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8128/3642304352.py", line 1
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver")
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is maybe because of escape sequence.
You need to add one more backslash like this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\chromedriver")
```

or else just add `r` before the path,

```
r"C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver
```